# Parallel disk writes C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

UPDATE I am totally aware that this is not going to add much benefit and the disk is going to be the bottleneck (although my disk can do 20k IOPS of 32K chunks) so please consider this before you decide to down vote.

============

I need to write the same file a 100 million times to a disk. I have 2 CPUs (16 threads each, 32 in total).

I would like to use all threads and do this in an asynchronous manner. The code is very simple. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            File.Copy(@"c:\sourcefile.txt", @"c:\distinationFile" + i + ".txt", true);
        }
```

What is the best way to do this with C#?

Comment: Do you need to fill disk with the same file or just have 10^10 files with same content (hard/soft links)?

Comment: Depending on the type of disk, this is probably not a good idea. You seem to be under the impression that this is a CPU bound problem ("I would like to use all threads"), whereas the bottleneck is how quickly the disk can write the data you are giving it, and the overhead introduced by having to overlap multiple jobs.

Comment: In whatever scenario you choose, the IO will be the bottleneck and parallel copying is not going to make your disk IO any faster. If you are writing to a spindle disk, using a single thread and asynchronous write-through I/O is your best bet.

Comment: You can also probably save a lot of time if you don't read from `"sourcefile.txt"` over and over, and instead read it into memory once before writing it multiple times.

Comment: Updated the post. Thanks for your concerns. I was only interested in the C#y way of doing it. I cannot share what is the business rational behind it unfortunately.

Comment: @RonaDona Alright, but please do consider using something other than `File.Copy`, especially if you're parallelizing the job; you have many threads trying to get the disk to read the input file over and over again when all you need is one read.

Comment: Read up on _I/O completion ports_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about "best", but you can use the TPL

```
ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.For(0, 100000000, i => { 
   File.Copy(@"c:\sourcefile.txt", @"c:\destinationFile" + i + ".txt", true);
});
```

Comment: Side note: running multiple disk IO operations in parallel often slow process down rather than speed it up on conventional (non SSD) drives... :)